# AJAX login/register login works only once

Tags: ajax, users

I'm using an [AJAX login/register module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_register). And there are two links: Login and Register. If I click login and then close it, I can click again and it will open. But if I click register, close it and click it again, it doesn't load, it is just showing me the loading bar. What's the problem?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the module or a conflict with another module. Perhaps providing some detail about the module/s you are using and your Drupal setup will generate some answers.

Comment: found my issue. i added another jquery library. so there were some conflicts between them and some scripts doesn't work